# On Windows 8.1, how do you screenshot using the monitor's current color profile?

Tags: windows-8, adobe-photoshop, colors, screenshot, color-profiles

How do you capture a screenshot on Windows 8.1 that uses the monitor's current color profile? My screenshots always have to have a color profile applied in Photoshop to look the same as the desktop.

Comment: Is your screen calibrated correctly? [By correctly, I mean with a colorimeter, not by eye]

Comment: Yes. I have an hardware calibrator.

Comment: Then your PShop workflow should include it, automatically.

Comment: I'm just using photoshop to check the profile. I could use any other software. The problem is the screenshot tool doesn't include the current profile and I can't find one that does.

Comment: ahh, of course, the windows clipping tool is just a copy to clipboard. Sorry, I'm used to Mac, which saves a png with correct profile. I guess you're looking at a 3rd party solution. I don't know of any off-hand, your Google would be as good as mine, sorry.